# Proper terminology for the types of dual

Tags: terminology, grammatical-number, paucal

I was reading an article about typology of Russian language by Gasparov, B. M. (“Structure of Russian language from typological point of view (Intro to sociogrammatics). Article 2. Morphology of the noun”. *Scholarly notes of Tartu University*, issue 486. Tartu, 1979. Pp. 23—44.) and in the section about grammatical number there is passage where I am not sure how to translate certain terminology in English. I am native Russian speaker, I just do not know the proper linguistic terms.

Below is the passage from page 32 <sup>([Rus](https://dspace.utlib.ee/dspace/bitstream/handle/10062/25795/acta_486_problemy_1979.pdf?sequence=1#page=33))</sup> where he talks about the general development of dual and then its extinction in Russian language, translated to the best of my ability (terms in question are emboldened, author’s own emphasis of one of the words is converted to italics by me):

> Most ancient stratum of the functioning of this form, apparently, constitute the so-called **independent dual** — the form used with a noun outside of combination with the numeral “two”, that is, not supported by lexical definition of quantity. Independent dual was used originally for designation of *paired* objects (“eyes”, “arms” and the like). Subsequently develops the usage of **connected dual** [related? bounded?] that combines the noun with the numeral “two”. As a result, the usage of the form of dual grammatical number broadens, and this form becomes universal quantitative determinant that can be imparted to any noun.

To elaborate more on “connected dual” author examples (p. 33) how relics of dual forms now differ in meaning according to whether or not they are used with a qualifier, such as numeral “two” or pronouns “these”, “such”, “mine”, “some” *etc.* If someone says “*на столе лежат книги*” (there are books laying on the table), listener would assume a “larger multitude” of “more than two” (>2), whereas “*эти книги лежат на столе*” (these books are laying on the table) means that there could be any number of books, including two (>1). That is, author argues that if there were, in fact, two books on the table, the speaker is expected to note that directly, or qualify that he is talking about specific objects (again, akin the definite article).

For me, as a native speaker, it is not readily intuitive, but I do agree that author is onto something.

### Old Russian dual and its relics in modern Russian

To shed more light on what the author talked about, below are several examples of Old Russian dual and its relics that remained after its extinction:

The modern word *рука* (NOM SG F) meaning “arm” is the same in Old Russian save for the digraph [*ѹ*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uk_%28Cyrillic%29) in place of *у* (both have similar or identical sound). NOM PL is the *рѹкы* (modern *руки*), and NOM-ACC-VOC DU is *рѹцѣ* which has no modern counterpart (although the numeral “two” follows the same paradigm for the F: modern *две* was *дъвѣ*). If that points to anything, this form is the same for DAT SG and LOC SG.

Now, in modern Russian there is no dual, but there is, we could say, paucal form for plural of 1.5, 2, 3, and 4. In case of *рука* and several other words it is formed with the same word as uncounted plural, but with the stress shift. “Two hands” is *две руки́*, but uncountable “hands” is *ру́ки*. From 5 to 20 GEN PL form is used: *13 рук*. After that combined numerals begin.

### Question

From the article it is unclear to me what author means exactly by “connected dual”. As he writes “connected dual that combines the noun with the numeral ‘two’”, does it not defeat the whole idea of dual? Although examples of Old Russian dual <sup>([Rus](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE#.D0.9F.D1.80.D0.B8.D0.BC.D0.B5.D1.80.D1.8B_.D1.83.D0.BF.D0.BE.D1.82.D1.80.D0.B5.D0.B1.D0.BB.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.B8.D1.8F_.D0.B4.D0.B2.D0.BE.D0.B9.D1.81.D1.82.D0.B2.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.BD.D0.BE.D0.B3.D0.BE_.D1.87.D0.B8.D1.81.D0.BB.D0.B0), Wikipedia)</sup> show that it could have been used both with or without numeral “two”. Gasparov also notes that after usage of dual had broadened, dual for paired objects took on function similar to that of definite article in English: *рѹцѣ* [dual, the arms, both arms, arms of one person] vs. *рѹкы* [plural, arms].

What are the correct linguistic terms for these particular types? Did I translate correctly? Please, link authoritative source or glossary, and bear in mind that I am not a linguist, so nothing excessively recondite.

Comment: I guess, this phenomenon perfectly fits into a distinction between Dual versus Plural, hence there's no additional term for it. Interestingly, although called *dual*, in Russian it applies to "tiny plural" (2, 3, and 4) contrary to "larger plural" (5 and above). The same article also points that composite numerals (`fifty-three eyes`) also follow the rule of "tiny plural" versus, e.g. `twenty-eight eyes`.

Comment: @bytebuster, it was full and proper dual. “Tiny plural” for “small multitudes” of 2, 3, and 4 is a relic of the dual. They still have to be used with numeral quantifier, whereas Old Russian _брата_ (nominative dual) meant “two brothers”, and only two.

Comment: if you are talking about a category which usually means 2, but can be 3 or 4, this is called  *paucal* number. if it is a number that is at least 3, you can call it plural, and if it is 2 or more, you can call it non-singular. the correct choice depends on the overall distinctions available.

Comment: @jlovegren, no, there is no paucal in Russian. It is just a relic of dual — the declension form for old nominative dual is used to designate plurality for “small multitudes” (still have to be used with a numeral): 1 _стол_ → 2 _стола_ → 3 _стола_ → 4 _стола_ → 5 _столов_. I cannot just say _стола_ and expect people to understand it as “two tables” (or 3, or 4). In fact, that form would mean nothing today without a numeral or preposition to designate it as pl., or sg. genitive, or sg. accusative in modern Russian

Comment: @theUg You can't either say `столов` without numeral. You can say a simple plural `столы`, but it can't be used with any numeral.

Comment: @bytebuster it is true, but it does not make my statements any less true either.

Comment: Could you make a list of the following sentences, each in a plural and in a dual variant, and give their approximate (modern) meaning/implication? By the latter I mean tell us how many books you would expect, or say "incorrect" if it is never used that way. You could just write out 16 part-sentences in English like this (or leave out the ones you deem irrelevant):
1. Books *(pl.)* are lying on the table. 
1.b. Books *(du.)* are lying on the table. 
2. These books... 
3. Two books... 
4. These two books... 
5. Three books... 
6. These three books... 
7. Six books... 
8. These six books...

Comment: @Cerberus, if you ask me to list Old Russian declension, I cannot. I know next to nothing about the respective grammar, and even though I might be able to figure out how to write some of it from the linguistic literature I have access to, it would be at least unreliable. Hell, I cannot even pronounce _руцѣ_, for instance.

Comment: @theUg: No, no, I meant modern usage!

Comment: @Cerberus `A book` is maybe not the best example since it is feminine, and many fem. nouns show *syncretism* between a simple plural form and the form being discussed (for 2-3-4 objects).

Comment: @bytebuster: Okay, whichever word you think is best.

Comment: @Cerberus Allright, "the table", `стол` (masc.) [stol]. Plural nominative (capitals are mine): столЫ [sto'lɨ]; 1,21,31,41,51... стол [stol] (no ending, regardless of plural); 2-4,22-24,32-34... столА [sto'la]; 5-20,25-30,35-40... столОВ [sto'lov]. "The" and "these" don't make any difference and decline as above. All above is only nominative. Other declensions do not differ with number. Again, with an exception of Accusative: 1,21,31,41... стол, the others are столОВ [sto'lov]. In general, I agree with @jlovegren it is very similar to **paucal**, but I've never seen this term as per Russian.

Comment: @Cerberus, so I also added the F example in the question, but I still strongly insist it is irrelevant, because I think author just talks about general evolution of dual in PIE languages at that point.

Comment: @bytebuster, @ theUg: Thanks. This makes it more complex, and you seem to disagree on "these" and on the distinctive value of the dual with and without a number. I still don't feel that I fully understand how it works in modern Russian, but I don't think there is a name for this specific phenomenon.

Comment: Perhaps there is a name for the phenomenon where a morphological feature that used to be able to mark a certain function on its own but now requires another feature, but I doubt it; *independent dual* v. *dependent dual* makes sense in this context, provided that the reader fully understands how it works, or any of the other words proposed.

Answer (score 2):

I think I can help you. Parallels exists in modern Slovenian and Croatian.

In Slovenian, you would use dual with any two objects:

> Matjaž in Janez *sta* *bila*... (dual of verb) "Matjaž and Janez were"...
>
> Dva človeka *sta* *bila* (dual of verb) "Two men were"...

This is, I suppose, "independent dual", the same thing you had in Old Church Slavic and is somehow preserved in Slovenian.

In Croatian, you would use dual/paucal **only** if words for 2, 3, 4 or "both" are present:

> Matjaž i Janez su *bili* (only plural possible)
>
> Dva čovjeka su *bila* (dual/paucal of past participle)

I think that's the "connected" dual, like in Russian. It's restricted to constructs where words for 2, 3, 4 or "both" appear, it's not enough to have A and B, you must have the word *two* somewhere to trigger dual.

Maybe "restricted" or "bound" dual is a better term, since it's use is bound to some specific numerals. Hope this helps you a bit.

For various views on dual, check this work, pages 40-91, especially page 85.

http://arizona.openrepository.com/arizona/bitstream/10150/297021/2/azu_etd_12790_sip1_m.pdf

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, some nouns had at first inherently dual meaning, but eventually there was a development where an affix historically deriving from the word meaning "two" began used as a generic dual marker. The first usage might be called the **lexical dual**, and the second the **morphological dual**.

Comment: These two terms, are they widely used in linguistics? Also, the dual in Old Russian (let’s say up until the XIV century when (according to the article I quoted) it began to disintegrate) was a fully developed category (see [declension paradigm tables](http://phil-vsu.narod.ru/dl/3k/5_istgram1.pdf)), which, methinks, is different from pseudo-dual the terms you referenced might indicate. While I would admit I do not fully comprehend the article I quoted, as far as I understand, Old Russian dual was used without numeral quantifier (_руцѣ_ [dual, both arms] vs. _рукы_ [plural, arms]).

Comment: I don't know anything about Russian, but, if its "old dual" is anything like Greek or Proto-Indo-European dual, I would not call it lexical. It has its own set of endings just like singular and plural; it's just that it is not used much except with certain nouns that can occur in pairs, such as, indeed, eyes and arms, but also horses, and people. I would rather call "morphological dual", or just "dual". The other sounds like our "a pair/couple of" but an older, more integrated form; one might call that "suffixed dual". P.S. Or, wait, did you mix up "first" and "second" usage in your answer?

Comment: @Cerberus you would know better than me. go ahead and put your comments in an answer.

Comment: @Cerberus, I am not clear as yet on this, but from the declension tables I linked above it can be seen that dual in Old Russian had been used with all kinds of words (there are exampled “stones”, “seeds” and so forth). The passage I quoted in OP explains general evolution of dual before delving in specifics of evolution of Dual in Russian. Author afterwards continues to explain how dual took on the function akin to the definite article in English (_e. g._ dual _eyes_ would be eyes of one person, not just any number of, so to say, disparate eyes designated by plural).

Comment: @theUg post some examples in the body of your question, showing singular, plural, and dual forms for each of the nouns in question, one set for the "old" dual and one set for the "new" dual.

Comment: @Cerberus: To clarify the last sentence in my previous comment, the function of definite article is taken by the dual for paired objects, whereas for all other objects the dual would just mean “any two of”.

Comment: @jlovegren I still don't feel qualified to answer, because I don't fully understand the way all this works. There appear to be two phenomena: Old Russian dual, and modern dual as inherited from Old Russian. I still haven't got a complete picture of 1.) when and how the modern dual is used, 2.) how it differs in meaning from plural.

Comment: @Cerberus sounds fair. i asked the OP to put up a couple of paradigms so we can make sense of it since I don't see anyone familiar with Russian visiting the question.

Comment: @jlovegren: Yeah I agree. See my comment to the question: do you think that would be enough?

Comment: @jlovegren: As to paradigms, I gather the modern dual still has (one/some of) the old form(s); my question is just about how it is used and what it means in contrast with plural.

Comment: @Cerberus, there's no dual in Modern Russian.

Comment: @AlexB.: Well, there is *something* resembling a dual. I was trying to figure out what best to call it based on its function. If it comes from the Old-Russian dual, that is an argument for calling it dual too, i.e. continuity and consistency with respect to history and form.